# addEventListener vs jquery.on and form.submit vs jquery.submit - difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events

I had a piece of code that registered callbacks using jQuery `on` (e.g. `$(formElement).on('submit', callback)` ) and somewhere in the application I was trying to trigger form submission using HTML Form element object (e.g. `formElement.submit()`) without using jQuery. However, event handlers were not called, but when I simply changed code to `$(formElement).submit()`, callbacks were called. So this is first question, why?

So I started to play around with different techniques of submitting / registering and this code works - callbacks were called (`$formElement` is jQuery object with length of 1):

```
$formElement.on('submit', function () {
    // do some stuff
});
$formElement.on('submit', function () {
    // do more stuff
});


setTimeout(function() {
    $formElement.submit();
}, 10000);
```

However changing it to :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $formElement[0].submit();
}, 10000);
```

Did not trigger callbacks. What is more, when I replaced `$formElement.on` with `$formElement[0].addEventListener` , callbacks were not called no matter how I trigger them (jQuery submit or HTML Form submit)

So probably I'm missing some fundamental knowledge about event handling. Could you help with that?

Comment: Does the form have an element with an `id` or `name` attribute set to `submit`?

Comment: Nope, name is name="createProfileForm", in console it renders as submit() { [native code] }

Comment: only `$formElement`has binding to the event, not `$formElement[0]`

Comment: so jquery submit event is not the same as DOM submit event ? For instance, analogous code but for click event works.

Comment: right, it's not the same. and click events are predefined allways bind to an element. i think there jquery works with the dom events.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with jquery but the .submit doesn't seem to actually submit the form but rather to register a listener to the submit event, whereas native .submit method on dom elements actually submits the form.

Here is a way to both listen to manual submission and to trigger a submission after 10 seconds:

```
  const form = document.getElementById('someform');

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    alert('form submitted');
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));
    form.submit();
  }, 10000);
```

I'm manually dispatching a submit event because the submit method seems to submit the form but not to trigger the event.